# Eclipse ADT Plugin - No Build Target Available

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When trying to create a new Android Project with Eclipse, there is no Build Target available.

***I have:***

- Installed ADT Plugin
- Created a virtual device
- Installed Android SDK, installed platform + platform tools
- Set the Android SDK path to Eclipse.

I have tried every fix I have found, but they just tell me to do those things I just mentioned.

**EDIT:**

In Window -> Preferences -> Android, it accepted my path, but there is No target avaible there.

And yes, I have installed:

Android SDK tools, revision 10
Android SDK platform-tools, revision 3
SDK platform Android 2.2 API 8, revision 2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set your SDK home once again in your Android Preferences on Eclipse.

Comment: Execute C:\Users\Timppa\Desktop\Android\android-sdk-windows\android (I think it's a BAT file) , go to "Available Packages" and see if you can install something from "Android Repository". Preferably an SDK platform.

Comment: I have already installed 2.2 platform that way. Is it bad if I just install everything?

Comment: It's not if you have the time (some of them are very large packages, depending on your Internet connection speed).

Comment: Please see if this platform appears in "installed packages". Maybe it all got deleted or something.

Comment: It does appear in installed packages among sdk tools and platform tools. I try to download some additional stuff in case I miss something as that can't at least harm me...

Comment: Solved it! I expanded the Android-menu, checked every possible submenu from there. I did not change anything, but once I returned back to the main Android-menu, Android 2.2 had magically appeared there... I seriously don't know what happened, but it helped!

Comment: Great! What a strange situation.

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse after doing this

Comment: @VicentePlata I have no idea why the avd manager in Eclipse and when I run the "android" command aren't the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, preferences->android page's targets list was empty even when pointing to a valid SDK location on Ubuntu 10.10. Eclipse restart solved the problem.

Comment: this fixed things for me too, on OSX

Answer (score 1):

To create a Virtual Device

- Run `\android\tools\android.bat`
- `Virtual Devices` -> `New`

Add this device as your target.

Comment: I already have added a Virtual Device like I have mentioned, it appears in the menu as a Valid Android Virtual Device, but still it does not appear as a Preference menu target

Comment: What is the SDK location you gave?

Comment: C:\Users\Timppa\Desktop\Android\android-sdk-windows, that is where I have extracted the SDK.

Comment: It seems fine. Maybe you need to update your eclipse ADT plugin

Comment: I downloaded it few hours ago so it should be updated. Tried updating anyways, no updates found.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Finally I resolved this by the following steps:

1. Window > Preferences.
2. Go to General > Startup and Shutdown: Select Android Development Toolkit.
3. Restart Eclipse.
4. Now the list of SDK Targets appeared correctly in Preference > Android page.

The reason is that I disabled some plugins to speed up my Eclipse sometime ago, I need to enable them once again in the aforementioned place.

Comment: Worked perfectly! This should be closer to the top.

Answer (score 0):

So you try to create a new Android Project with Eclipse, there is no Build Target available.
Please Goto **Window -> Android SDK Manager**. Now try to install all new updates. After all installation finished, restart your ADT or Eclipse. Problem may resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, none of the above solutions worked for me.

I uninstalled the Eclipse Android tools and reinstalled them, this of course required two Eclipse restarts. Net effect the targets showed uo again correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the Eclpise and check if it works. Still problem persist then once again set the **SDK Location** by going to **windows->preference->android**